# SCSS how can I group and reuse a block of classes and styles?

Tags: css, sass, breakpoints

I have a component that uses media queries to add new styles on the `medium-up` breakpoint.

The SCSS looks something like this:

```scss
.mycomponent {
  // Bunch of mobile-first styles and classes
    
    @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
      // Bunch of styles and classes for medium and up.
    }
}
```

However, I now want to add a modifier that essentially adds the medium-and-up styles on large-and-up instead.

I can do this as such, using the `:not` selector:

```scss
.mycomponent {
  // Bunch of mobile-first styles and classes
}

.mycomponent:not(.mycomponent--lg) {
    @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
      // Bunch of styles and classes that appear on med-up
    }
}

.mycomponent--lg {
    @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
      // Bunch of styles and classes identical to above but now appearing on lg-up
    }
}
```

HTML would look like:

```html
<div class="mycomponent">Shows different styling on medium and up</div>
<div class="mycomponent mycomponent--lg">Shows different styling on large and up</div>
```

The above SCSS works, but I've got a lot of duplication. The styles and classes between each breakpoint are identical.

Apart from placing the styles on their own file and using `@import`, is there any way to group them on the same page and just pull them into each breakpoint when I need them?

Comment: If I understand your issue correctly, you could use a `%placeholder` block that you would extend in each media queries.

Comment: @AmauryHanser yes that would be ideal. But I cannot seem to get it to work with nested selectors.

Comment: looks like you're right about the placeholder not working in the media query if it's was not it's original context, sorry. You could use a mixin instead!

Comment: Yep the mixin worked best. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

SCSS's `%placeholder` would have been a good idea, but they don't seem to work when placed in media queries.

Instead I had to make a `mixin`:

```
.mycomponent {
  // Bunch of mobile-first styles and classes
}

@mixin desktopStyles {
  // Bunch of styles and classes for larger break points
}

.mycomponent:not(.mycomponent--lg) {
    @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
        @include desktopStyles;
    }
}

.mycomponent--lg {
    @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
        @include desktopStyles;
    }
}
```